# Apache: Options +Indexes still results in 403 Forbidden or Apache Test Page

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, http-status-code-403

On a local dev server, I have an Apache conf for a website like so

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin no-reply@localhost
  ServerName sandbox.mysite.internal
  DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/sandbox/mysite
  ErrorLog logs/sandbox/mysite-error.log
  CustomLog logs/sandbox/mysite-access.log common
</VirtualHost>
```

If I visit the following address (there is no index.php or index.html)

```
http://sandbox.mysite.internal
```

I get the Apache CentOS test page

If I visit a subdirectory like

```
http://sandbox.mysite.internal/test/
```

I get a `403 Forbidden` error. So I add the following `.htaccess` here:

```
/var/www/vhosts/sandbox/mysite/test/.htaccess
```

Content:

```
Options +Indexes
```

Now when I visit:

```
http://sandbox.mysite.internal/test/
```

I still get 403 Forbidden.

How do I make the directory index show up?

I always thought `.htaccess` directives override any `httpd.conf` directives. But am I wrong about that? Is there some setting in my `httpd.conf` that is making my `.htaccess` directive be ignored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, `AllowOverride None` would prevent `.htaccess` files from functioning.  But, why use them at all?  Apache's [recommendation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html#when) is to never use `.htaccess` unless you are unable to access the main configuration.

Try this, instead:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin no-reply@localhost
  ServerName sandbox.mysite.internal
  DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/sandbox/mysite
  ErrorLog logs/sandbox/mysite-error.log
  CustomLog logs/sandbox/mysite-access.log common
  <Directory /var/www/vhosts/sandbox/mysite/test/>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Options +Indexes
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

If that doesn't work, have a look at Apache's error log; you may have something wrong with your file/directory permissions, for example.

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thanks! The only reason I was using the `.htaccess` is because it's convenient to add/remove that file at will to make quick adjustments, even if temporary.

Comment: @Jakobud Gotcha - and that's just fine for a development/sandbox environment.  Well, if that worked, then it was either the `Order` and `Allow` directives that I added in the `Directory` block, or else you do indeed have an `AllowOverride None`, or perhaps an `AccessFileName` changing the name from the default (`.htaccess`)?

Comment: Ah yes I believe `AllowOverride None` was set in the `httpd.conf`. Thanks!

Comment: How would this look for Apache 2.4?

Answer (score 0):

If your parent directory .htaccess (or your Apache configuration file httpd.conf) prohibits directory access by default (as it should), then you will have to add a "Require all granted" directive to your .htaccess file so that the directory listing can be served. Otherwise, visitors will see a 403 (access forbidden) error.

For this to be safe, ensure that your directory and its files allow reading but prohibit writing (unless you actually want users to be able to alter or store files on your server). This advice assumes your server runs on Linux, which has a visible permissions feature. Windows servers may require more advanced security precautions.